# What is the best way to get my application featured on the EventBrite website?

Tags: eventbrite

How can I display my email marketing application (for sending invitations as newsletters) on the EventBrite website?

Answer (score 0):

Eventbrite does not usually promote third-party solutions within their main product.
I would start by applying to be listed in their [application showcase](http://eventbrite.appstores.com).  If that works out well, then they may be interested in [following-up with a blog post](http://blog.eventbrite.com/eventbrite-partners-with-leading-invitation-engine-paperless-post/), or evaluating other opportunities for cross-promotion.